# Equality in dual space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, dual-spaces

If $H$ is a Hilbert space and $H^* $ is its dual and $(\cdot ,\cdot)$ is the inner product defined on $H$, $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ is the duality pairing.

If I want to prove that $u=u’$ in $H^*$, is it enough to show that $$(u,v)=(u’,v) \forall v \in H$$

And does this depends on the space where we take the elements, whether they are in $H$ or in $H^*$??

Comment: In an Hilbert space $H$ is isomorphic to $H^\star$. So what you want to show is enough if you take $v=u-u'$ (which is an element in $H$ under the identification).

Comment: @Yanko $H^1_0$ is  Hilbert ,right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by $H_0^1$. Is it the sobolev space?

Comment: Yes it is $H^1$ with zero on the boundary

Comment: In here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space they says it is indeed an Hilbert space in the special case where $H$ is $L^2$ of the Torus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if 
$$ 
\langle u, v\rangle  = \langle u', v\rangle \forall v \in H,
$$
then $u = u'$ per definition. What you are asking is if something similar holds if 
$$ 
( u, v)  = ( u', v) \forall v \in H.
$$
The issue is that a priori this statement does not really make sense. It only gets some meaning if you identify $H$ with $H'$ with the Riesz map, i.e. the isomorphism between $H$ and $H'$ guaranteed by the Theorem of Frechet-Riesz.

If you make the identification between $H$ and $H'$ then the question becomes: For $u,u' \in H$ does 
$$ 
( u, v)  = ( u', v) \forall v \in H.
$$
imply $u = u'$. The answer is yes, by taking $v = u-u'$ as pointed out in the first comment by Yanko.

Comment: What if I know that $u \in H$, can I write the duality pairing?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. If $u$ and $v$ are both in $H$ then the dual pairing between $u$ and $v$ only makes sense by identifying $u$ with an element of the dual space. You do that by considering the element $\tilde{u} \in H'$ which is the functional
$$
v \mapsto ( u, v).
$$

Comment: in case of Hilbert space ,can we always identify $H$ by $H^*$?

Comment: Indeed, that follows from the Riesz representation theorem.

Comment: So I can deduce that if $u \in H^*$ and $u \in H$ we can show that $\langle u,v \rangle =(u’,v)$

Comment: I have another independent question, is Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem valid for multi variable function. As I have written here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2765740/cauchy-lipschitz-theorem-with-multi-variables

Comment: Well, without identification $H^* \cap H = \emptyset$. In fact, $H^*$ is a space of functionals on $H$. So there is no $u \in H^*$ such that also $u\in H$. Moreover, I am a bit confused by $u'$ is in your last comment.

Did you have a look at the Riesz representation theorem? I think everything will become very clear once you have fully understood that theorem.

Comment: Ok , everything is clear now, thank you