# Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem with multi-variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

If we have the initial value problem $$y’(t)=f(t,y(t))$$ $$y(t_0)=y_0$$
Then if $f$ is Lipschitz continuous with respect to the second variable, then the IVP has a unique solution

Does Cauchy Lipschitz theorem holds if $$y(t)=(y_1(t),...,y_m(t))$$ ?

Comment: Yes.  See any (sufficiently modern) textbook on ODEs.

Comment: @user539887 and we prove $f$ Lipschitz in a similar way?

Comment: We do not *prove* Lipschitz:  it is an assumption.

Comment: But if we don’t have this assumption,we have to prove it, if it holds then we can apply the theorem

Comment: Yes, that's correct.